# Moving a row between sections

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a problem with my `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath` code.

It works fine when I'm moving cells within a section but when I try to move a row from one section (say from `indexPath [1,1]` to `indexPath [2,0]`) to another I get a crash with this error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 1 moved out).'

Here is my code, again, it works fine if the two indexPaths share the same section number:

```
- (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *cells = [[self cellsAtSectionOfIndexPath:indexPath] mutableCopy];
    Cell *cell = [self dataAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Cell *newCell = [self dataAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];

    if ([indexPath section] == [newIndexPath section])
    {
        [cells replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:newCell];
        [cells replaceObjectAtIndex:newIndexPath.row withObject:cell];
        [self replaceCellsAtIndexPath:indexPath withCells:cells];
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableArray *newCells = [[self cellsAtSectionOfIndexPath:newIndexPath] mutableCopy];
        [cells replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:newCell];
        [newCells replaceObjectAtIndex:newIndexPath.row withObject:cell];
        [self replaceCellsAtIndexPath:indexPath withCells:cells];
        [self replaceCellsAtIndexPath:newIndexPath withCells:newCells];
    }

    [super moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newIndexPath];
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your data source. The error means that you are removing a row from a section but the `numberOfRowsInSection:` method returns the same number when it should return the old number minus 1. Same thing with adding the row to the other section.

Comment: but the numberOfRowsInSection shouldn't change. am I not replacing the row at indexPath with newIndexPath and vice verse so shouldn't the number of rows be the same?

Comment: Well the idea of moving cells is to move a cell from one position to another, not to switch them. When the user moves a cell, it is done automatically. So the table view places the cell automatically in your new section. in the `moveRowAtIndexPath...` method you should only change your data source, you should not be messing with the cells here. Also, it is not good practice to hold a reference to each cell in your table view. You should reuse the cell, as it slides out from your screen.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks. I might be able to figure this out now.. And I'm not saving the actual cells in the array, I'm saving the cell data.

Comment: Ok, the class name was confusing (`Cell`). Then just delete the object from the source array, and insert it into the other one.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Yeah, it's called something else in my code but I thought I would change it to make it more general in the question but I guess I named it too hastily :)